# Return SessionFactory Singleton object for Hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am using Hibernate 4.3. I am trying to get the `SessionFactory` object from a `HibernateUtil` class. I am trying to get only one `SessionFactory` object for entire application, i.e. Singleton object for application.

Below is my current code, I want to make it Singleton class.

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry; 

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
      configuration.configure();
      serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
      sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
      return sessionFactory;
  }

}
```

Please suggest or provide sample code for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Make HibernateUtil a Singleton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested I have made the `HibernateUtil.java` class as Singleton.
Find the below code, and please suggest / comment to confirm the correctness of code.

Here is the updated code:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static HibernateUtil instance = null;

   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

   private HibernateUtil(){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
   }

   public static HibernateUtil getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance  = new HibernateUtil();
        }
        return instance;
   }

   public synchronized static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
   }

}
```

Please do correction if the code is not correct, and suggest the correct way.

Comment: Would suggest using a synchronized method to get the SessionFactory. Also, instantiating the class itself may be redundant and you would have to call getInstance() before getSessionFactory. Antoniossss' answer comes closest to achieving what you want

Answer (score 4):

Just apply singleton pattern

```
public class HibernateUtil {

  private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry; 
  private volatile static SessionFactory INSTANCE = null;

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if(INSTANCE==null){
      createSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  private synchronized static void createSessionFactory() {
    if(INSTANCE!=null){return;}

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();

    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    INSTANCE = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
  }
}
```

Edit: fixed a comma typo

Comment: What was the downvote for? Also, the first **if** is not using the conditional equals symbol

Comment: @Jaden thanks for the pointout - corrected comparison operator. I would like to know why the downvote as well ;)

Comment: To future readers: `serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build(); NSTANCE = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);` might break your code - I got `Not an entity` error. Using `NSTANCE = configuration.buildSessionFactory();` without `serviceRegistry` worked however.

Comment: @Antoniossss Why do you check inside 'createSessionFactory' function that instance != null if you call the function if instance is null?

Comment: For cases when you call it when it should not be called. Its just for programming error.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than making  HibernateUtil as singleton.Make SessionFactory as singleton.

```
 public class HibernateUtil {

       private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

       static {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
       }

       public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
             return sessionFactory;
       }
    }
```

Advantages of above approach as below

1.no synchronize code(avoiding locking and unlocking for each method call)
2.no if condition
3.sessionfactory is eagly instantiation.(static block will be executeted only once in class life time)
4.application starup itself you can find errors in configuration files.

please suggest/comments on this..

thanks